# What is the meaning of a flat metric invariant up to a Weyl factor?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, topology

When studying CFT I was told that:

**A conformal transformation is a spacetime transformation that leaves the flat metric invariant up to a Weyl factor.**

What is the meaning of leaving a metric invariant **up to a Weyl factor**?
I thought that leaving a metric invariant simply meant that the metric wouldn't change. What does it mean to be invariant up to a factor?

Comment: $ds^2 \to \Omega(x) ds^2$ i.e. the metric remains the same up to a space-time dependent scale factor.

Comment: So what it means is that the metric, $ds^2$ , is the same but has a factor of $\Omega(x)$  , in a very non-scientific language, like a zoom-in/out of one image (it doesn't change the image)??

Comment: Yes, very roughly speaking, you could think of it as zooming in and out---the zoom factor is dependent on $x$. Also note that $\Omega(x)$ should be assumed to be positive everywhere, otherwise the new metric degenerates there.